# How to add a new github token for an existing private repo?

Tags: git, github

I had to revoke the old Github token for a private repo.

Now generated a new token from Github.

How to add this old token to the existing repo?

Without updating this new token push/pull is failing:

```
git push origin master          
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for....
```

I know how to solve this problem if I can re-clone the repo. However, I want to avoid cloning the repo again.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the "authentication" section of the manual of the Git client you're using? If so, which client do you use and what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

I have to edit the `.git/config` and update the URL with the user correct token.

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://<user>:<token-id>@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Here `token-id` is set to the updated one.

Comment: Works for me. Do you know if it is considered safe/good practice to store token in `.git/config`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it in one line. Had the same problem. This worked for me:

```sh
git remote set-url origin https://<USER>:<TOKEN>@github.com/<USER>/<REPO>.git
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

GitHub tokens actually exist at an account level and not a repo level.

See these instructions on how to add a token to your account: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account